# Unable to Initialize a UITextView in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode10

This works in Xcode 9

```
private lazy var textField : UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    return tf
}()
```

With the same project in Xcode 10, this throws an compilation error. However in a new, fresh project, it compiles no problem. I have also tried to use the UITextField's grandparent's (UIView) initializer.

```
private lazy var textField : UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    return tf
}()
```

I am presented this time with the error: *Argument labels '(frame:)' do not match any available overloads*?

[image]

Comment: Your code creating a `UITextView` with a frame is working fine for me in Xcode 10.

Comment: It works fine for me in Xcode 10 also.

Comment: Your first example : `private lazy var textField : UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    return tf
}()` compiled with no issues or warnings in my Xcode 10.0 (10A255)

Comment: You are right, in a fresh Xcode project this compiles no error, updated the description